# Replacing only part of an iframe src

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to use javascript to change part of an iframe src, is there a way to change '500' to '800' in that iframe src? I tried the following code but it did not work. If anyone could help that'd be appreciated.

```
        function bigPhotosets() {
            $('iframe.photoset').each(function(){
                $(this).attr('src').replace('500','800');
                $(this).attr('width').replace('500','800');
            });
        }

        bigPhotosets();
```

Answer (score 3):

`.replace()` returns a new string, which you aren't doing anything with.

You need to set the `src` to this new string:

```
var newSrc = $(this).attr('src').replace('500','800');   
$(this).attr('src', newSrc);
```

There are also faster ways to do this.

Comment: This didn't work... see on http://jtestblog1.tumblr.com/post/26387860417/aquaticwonder-dancing-alone-portraits-by-caiti

Answer (score 0):

This code is just returnin the src attribute, replacing some text and doing nothing more. Try this:

```
$(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('500','800') );
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe SLaks' answer is correct. When I used his code in the console on your tumblr page, it changed the source correctly. The width didn't change however, and the height needs to be adjusted.

I pasted the following code into the console (on Chrome) on http://jtestblog1.tumblr.com/post/26387860417/aquaticwonder-dancing-alone-portraits-by-caiti and it worked as you say it needs to work.

```
function bigPhotosets() {
    $('iframe.photoset').each(function(){
        var newSrc = $(this).attr('src').replace('500','800');
        $(this).attr('src', newSrc).width(800).height(912);
    });
}

bigPhotosets();
```

I would be worried about another `500` existing in your URL. This would mess up the URL. If it's always going to be at the end of the URL you might want to use a regex that will only replace 500 if it only occurs at the end of the URL.

i.e. change the 3rd line to

```
var newSrc = $(this).attr('src').replace(/500$/,'800');
```

It will only work if 500 is at the end of the URL (which if the size is always going to be at the end of the URL, that's a good thing). On your tumblr, the size *is* at the end of the URL, so this regex works.

Comment: didn't work.. what am I doing wrong? http://jtestblog1.tumblr.com/post/26387860417/aquaticwonder-dancing-alone-portraits-by-caiti & I changed the theme again and now it's 600 so the 912 would need to change 1, and also some photosets have more amounts of photos so I can't use a set height.

Comment: I don't know. I changed `500` to `600` in my snippet, pasted it into the console on your page, and it worked again. You can't have an "auto" height for an iframe, so that may prove troublesome.

Comment: You do have an error: "infinitescroll is not a function" on line 1216. That may be why you're having issues.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way. Replace the old src with the same src but with 500 replaced with 800.

```
$(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('500','800') );
```

**In your link in the comments for the first answer it doesn't work because there is no *500* but a *600* in the iframe src.**

Also note that you will have to take care of both the width attribute and the css width.

Which would give you

```
$(this).attr('width', 800);
$(this).css('width', 800);
```

After this the only thing left is to adjust the height of the iframe proportionally to how you changed the width. Which is oldHeight*800/500 (or in your actual case 800/600).